# Why the tests are not running ? ( Golang ) - goapp test - bug?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to run [GAE](http://blog.golang.org/appengine-dec2013) tests on multiple packages.  My app (testapp ) looks as below:

```
testapp> 
README.md     package1 package2
```

each package has two go files. One is the package itself the other is the 'test' package.

**package1**

```
$ls package1
package1.go package1_test.go
```

**package2**

```
$ls package2
package2.go package2_test.go
```

To run the tests I use

```
goapp test -v ./...
```

Output:

```
 warning: building out-of-date packages:
        github.com/mihai/API
    installing these packages with 'go test -i ./...' will speed future tests.

    === RUN TestGetDiskFile
    codelistgobfile.gob
    codelist.gob written successfully
    --- PASS: TestGetDiskFile (0.00 seconds)
    PASS
    ok      testapp/package1    0.010s
```

However  as you can see above it seems to run  only the first test ( TestGetDiskFile ) from  `package1`.  After that it gets stuck. I get no kind of output.  If I go in each package ( `cd package 1` ) and run `goapp test` all the tests (about 20 tests) run successfully

Any idea how I can fix / run all the tests without getting stuck or at least how I can debug it further? is this a `goapp` bug?
 I've tried on two different machines ( Mac osx , and ubuntu ), the result is same.

Comment: Have same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I think I did but unfortunately I forgot to post the solution.