# Go not running some tests

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing

I'm new to Golang and I'm trying to run some tests from a golang app.
Tests are running at a docker container with a Golang 1.12.

My problem is that some tests appear to be running correctly, but others do not.

Example:

I have a function that I wanted to fail on purpose.

```
func TestLol(t *testing.T) {
    assert.EqualValues(t, 1, 2)
    t.Fail()
}
```

When I execute the docker container with a "docker run ... go test -v ./..." it should run all tests and about this function on specific it should fail, but what happens that it doesn't fail. Golang just log a "ok" beside the test.

Then I tried to run only the folder with test file that should fail.

Log:

```
ok      github.com/eventials/csw-notifications/services 0.016s
2021/09/25 21:08:44 Command finished successfully.
Tests exited with status code: 0
Stopping csw-notifications_db_1     ... done
Stopping csw-notifications_broker_1 ... done
Going to remove csw-notifications_app_run_ed70597b5c20, csw-notifications_db_1, csw-notifications_broker_1
Removing csw-notifications_app_run_ed70597b5c20 ... done
Removing csw-notifications_db_1                 ... done
Removing csw-notifications_broker_1             ... done
```

**My question is why golang dosn't output any log with a FAIL message for this file in specific?**

I think it's somewhat related to this question, but as it didn't received any answear I'm reposting it.

[Why the tests are not running ? ( Golang ) - goapp test - bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772907/why-the-tests-are-not-running-golang-goapp-test-bug)

EDIT: I'm editting to this question be more clear.

Comment: In which file have you added TestLol? You say "In this example the /services/ doesn't ran." but at the bottom of the output, it says that `ok github.com/.../app/services  0.013s` indicating that services was run and all tests passed.

Comment: I've added on both files. I said it didn't ran, because it should fail, but it didn't. So I'm guessing the test didn't went through all test functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that a import was causing this issue.

Every test file importing porthos-go or porthos-go/mock isn't running the test files. Removing those imports fixed my problem.

lib: https://github.com/porthos-rpc/porthos-go

I still don't know why, but when I do I'll update this answear.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try add -timeout
If your test files contain FuncTest with samenames rename.
You can try change output to `go test -v -json ./...`

```
    -timeout d
        If a test binary runs longer than duration d, panic.
        If d is 0, the timeout is disabled.
        The default is 10 minutes (10m).
```

Comment: I think i got the right result.

`{"Time":"2021-09-25T20:51:09.137402228Z","Action":"output","Package":"github.com/.../.../services","Output":"ok  \tgithub.com/..../.../services\t0.015s\n"}
{"Time":"2021-09-25T20:51:09.137427418Z","Action":"fail","Package":"github.com/.../.../services","Elapsed":0.015}
2021/09/25 20:51:09 Command finished successfully.`

Could you explain why some tests have an "FAIL" log when tests do fail, and others do not?

Comment: @BrenoAlves
You see PASS because your tests don't receive a signal of failer. Maybe you create a test and forgot send t.Fail() or condition inside IF don't return t.Fail() or similiar.

Try this: 
```if assert.EqualValues(t, 1, 2) {
  // ok it is equal
} else {
 // error not equal
 t.Fail()
}```
assert.Equal will return true or false, you need if to decide what happen next.

Comment: @BrenoAlves create `func TestName(t *testing.T) { t.Fail()}`
Createa another one `func ExampleName() { fmt.Println("hi") } //Output: hi`
To see some logs in test, you need stop use fmt.Println and change to log or logf. 


try this and before t.Fail() `t.Logf("Expected %d, got %d", expected, actual)`

This is only for files ends in _test.go ex: Name_test.go

Answer (score 0):

main.go

```
func Start(s ...string) {
  fmt.Println(s)
}
```

main_test.go

```
func TestStart(t *testing.T) {
    Start("rocket")

    if 0 == 1 {
        t.Log("Houston, we have a problem")
        t.Fail()
    }
}

func ExampleStart() {
    fmt.Println("Ground Control to Major Tom")
    // Output:
    // Ground Control to Major Tom
}
```

Change if condition to 0 == 0 to see Fail with somelogs.

Comment: In my test function i was calling t.Fail(), but didn't workout. I found out that an import was making unable to run the test file, I don't know why tho